# How do I get apt-get to reinstall a package and run the set up scripts?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

So I installed mailutils (apt-get install mailutils) and when I did a nice little setup screen popped up and started asking me questions. I guess I screwed up and cancelled out before I had all the data I need to configure. Anyhow, how do I get it to rerun that setup script?

PBI

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can try with

```
dpkg-reconfigure -plow <PACKAGE>
```

This will ask again the configuration questions about the package. It may ask you to reconfigure related packages as well.

Comment: What's the equivalent for debian 9? this command doesn't exists on my system. I've a lot of `dpkg-*` commands, but not this.

Answer (score 11):

Mailutils itself doesn't really have any specific configuration, as it's merely a collection of various mail utilities.

One of the dependencies of mailutils is the default-mta package which in ubuntu, is postfix. Postfix would have gotten installed when you ran `apt-get install mailutils`, and it's the postfix configuration screen you likely saw.

To re-run this configuration wizard, just run: `$ dpkg-reconfigure postfix`.

Answer (score 4):

You have two possibilities, reinstall the package (maybe you have to purge it and install again) or just reconfigure it (this is preferable):

`dpkg-reconfigure mailutils`

Comment: The mailutils package really has no configuration (other than setting some /etc/alternatives options). The configuration dialogue mentioned was for postfix, not mailutils. See the files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` for more info...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, debian package installations can be rerun by running the postinst executable file cached by dpkg.

At least on my Ubuntu box, they can be found under `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`. The file should be named `<package-name>.postinst`.

Comment: This is actually not true, the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/package.postinst` will re-run the setup instructions but without asking the questions, the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/package.config` script is the one who ask them and reconfigures everything, so if you wanna repeat the process manually you would need to call it with the `reconfigure` parameter.