# How do I re-run the post-install set up script after making the wrong choice in apt install mailutils?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-22.04

Yes - I have read [this similar Q and all the answers](https://serverfault.com/q/474361/515728). Unfortunately that was from years ago, and none of the answers work any longer.

I'm running an Ubuntu server 22.04, and installed `mailutils`. Near the end of my first installation, I got a "window" (ncurses??) that popped up in the terminal, asking what type of install I wanted to do. Being ignorant, I went with the default "Internet", and learned later that the correct choice for my situation was "Satellite".

I can find no way to revert that decision. I have un-installed/removed, purged, re-booted and re-installed `mailutils` multiple times now, but that "window" will not reappear. It's rather frustrating... Does anyone know how to rectify this??

##### EDIT 1:

FWIW, here's a list of the dependencies installed:

> The following NEW packages will be installed:
> gsasl-common guile-3.0-libs libgc1 libgsasl7 libidn12 libltdl7 libmailutils8 libmysqlclient21 libntlm0 libpq5 mailutils mailutils-common mysql-common

Comment: Are you sure that was about mailutils? This question more likely was asking about some MTA, e.g. Postfix, Exim, etc.. If that's the case, ignore that dialog, as you are want to customize MTA configuration for your purpose anyway, or you don't need an MTA.

Comment: I am not interested in what happened in someone's case of 10 years old. I was asking about **your particular case**. Many packages might be installed as a result of running a single command due to dependencies, and I presume mailutils might have a dependency on MTA. By the way, you can still consult what really was installed in `/var/log/dpkg.log`, and hopefully it even disclose which package configuration window it was.

Comment: It might be helpful if you extract a list of all packages that were installed during that particular run. We can try to figure out which one you need to reconfigure.

Comment: Look here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mailutils it has a dependency on a virtual package `default-mta` which defaults to Postfix. `dpkg-reconfigure postfix`.

Comment: You may attempt to *fix* your installation with `apt install -f`. If that succeeds, resolve further. As to prevent this, better don't install debs like that, always pull from repository with apt. If you were provided with a deb file, better create your own repo and install from it. That said, this deviates from the question too much.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: You were correct; `dpkg-reconfigure postfix` did it; the post-install script appeared immediately, and allowed me to configure for "Satellite". If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll upvote & accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recognise
*internet* and *satellite* as choices on the exim configuration and it is reasonable to assume that exim is a dependancy of `mailutils`.
so `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` (or `dpkg-reconfigure postfix`, or `dpkg-reconfigure <whatever-the-MTA-is>`) will let you revisit those choices.

Comment: These options appear not for exactly Exim but **for any MTA** available: Exim, Postfix, Sendmail. One needs to actually review *which one* they actually had installed and act accordingly. By default Ubuntu is shipped with **Postfix**, (`default-mta` resolves to `postfix`), so most likely one needs to run `dpkg-reconfigure postfix`.

Comment: Yeah - I get your thinking on this, but unfortunately Exim is not a dependency of the `mailutils` package. I've edited my question to include the dependencies - does that help?

Comment: It doesn't have a *direct* dependency. It depends on `default-mta`, which could be *provided* by any MTA available. By default it will resolve to `postfix`, but if you already had exim installed, it wouldn't change that and accept exim as MTA.

Comment: That's sound thinking. Turns out that it was `postfix` that needed the reconfig. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
Dpkg-reconfigure mailutils
```

Remember this Linux command very good. It allows you to rerun the package installation when something goes wrong

Edit / Update
And when you try to remove the package completely including dependent packages, and then manually try to install by downloading it

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mailutils/mailutils_3.14-1_amd64.deb
```

And then install using `dpkg -i`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried that while exhausting possibilities on [the similar Q](https://serverfault.com/q/474361/515728). When I run this command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mailutils`, it simply does nothing. (also tried with `--force` option - same result).

Comment: And when do `apt-get purge mailutils` and install again. You can also configure it manually using /etc/mailutils.conf. To see where the config is stored you can also run `mailutils info sysconfdir`

Comment: There is no `/etc/mailutils.conf`... there are three files in `/etc` that start wit `mail`: `mailcap`, `mailcap.order` and `mailname`

Comment: ... and I think I mentioned in my Question that I had *"un-installed/removed, purged, re-booted and re-installed mailutils multiple times"*, and I did try `dpkg-reconfigure` several times - even with the `--force` option.

Comment: I added an update to mu post for you to try. It could also be that you got the configuration of a dependent package like postfix or something like that

Comment: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mailutils:` ...    It seems this .deb package does not include all of the dependencies needed. You got one that includes the needed dependencies - or is there another way to do this??

Comment: Yeah that's what I already thought. Usually when you install the deb package it automatically resolves the dependencies. It suspect that somewhere while removing a dependency wasn't removed and still having the old configuration and that's why you don't see the reconfigure again. But based on the current level of information we have i can't tell where the dependency problem is. You could try `apt install -f`. -f = fix Hopefully that fixes it.